# finite additivity condition

Tags: probability-theory

The definition of a probability measure $ P $ requires countable aditivity: $ P \left( \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty P (A_n)$ whenever $ A_1, A_2, \ldots $ is a sequence of disjoint sets in the relevant sigma algebra. I don't understand the proof of the countable **finite** aditivity property:
$ P \left( \bigcup_{n = 1}^N A_n\right) = \sum_{n = 1}^N P (A_n)$. If someone could explain that to me that would be terrific.

Thanks

Comment: Just set $A_n=\emptyset$ for $n>N$.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right. But I don't understand why that proves the general case? Shouldn't it also be proven for sequences of including the ones where $ A_{n} \ne \emptyset $ for $ n > N $?
Isn't it true for all finite sequences of $ A_{n} $? I'm confused because it seems to me that using $ A_{n} = \emptyset $ for $ n > N $ just proves it for a specific case.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you mean. You're given a finite number of disjoint sets, say, $A_1,\cdots ,A_N$, and you want to prove $P(\bigcup_{n=1}^NA_n)=\sum_{n=1}^N P(A_n)$. So you construct a sequence $(B_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ setting $B_k=A_k$ for $1\le k\le N$ and $B_k=\emptyset$ for $k>N$. Then you apply the countable aditivity property to $B_1,B_2,\cdots$. What do you get?

Comment: Since countable additivity is a definition; there's no 'general case' to prove; countable additivity is an axiom.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sure you are correct. I just don't understand why it's ok to set a sequence in which some $ B_{k} = \emptyset $ as proof. As I understand it, the property is supposed to be true for any sequence. This seems (to me) equivalent to proving something using a special case ($ B_{k} = \emptyset $ for $ k > N $). Again, I think you are correct but I don't get it. I hope I'm being clear on why.

Comment: No, I don't understand where/why you're confused. See my answer and then please try again to explain what you don't understand.

Comment: You are not proving only a special case *for the statement you’re trying to prove* (finite additivity). You’re using a special case of a known result (countable additivity) to prove the general case of finite additivity.

Answer (score 7):

The definition of countable additivity says that $P ( \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_{n}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P ( A_{n} )$ whenever $ A_{1}, A_{2}, \dots $ is a sequence of disjoint sets in the relevant sigma algebra.

Assuming countable addivity, let's prove finite additivity, which says that $P ( \bigcup_{n = 1}^{N} A_{n}) = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} P ( A_{n} )$ whenever $ A_{1}, A_{2}, \dots A_{N} $ is a sequence of disjoint sets in the relevant sigma algebra. Given $ A_{1}, A_{2}, \dots A_{N} $, we note that $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}A_{n} = A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup \cdots \cup A_{N} = A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup \cdots \cup A_{N} \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \cdots.$$

The point of including all those empty sets in the union above is to obtain an infinite sequence of disjoint sets (since the empty set is disjoint from everything) so we can apply countable additivity. Doing so yields
$$
\begin{align*}
P (A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup \cdots \cup A_{N}) &= P(A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup \cdots \cup A_{N} \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \cdots) \\
&= P(A_{1}) + P(A_{2}) + \cdots + P(A_{N}) + P(\emptyset) + P(\emptyset) + \cdots \\
&= P(A_{1}) + P(A_{2}) + \cdots + P(A_{N}) + 0 + 0 + \cdots \\
&= P(A_{1}) + P(A_{2}) + \cdots + P(A_{N}).
\end{align*}
$$

Since the sequence $A_{1}, A_{2}, \ldots, A_{N}$ was arbitary, we're done.

Comment: Right!! They key sentence to me is the last one. Because $ A_{1}, ..., A_{N} $ is arbitrary! and by adding the empty sets one can get to an infinite sequence of disjoint sets and the starting point was that ANY infinite sequence of disjoint sets can be used in the infinite countable additivity property therefore the proof is good for ANY finite disjoint sequence!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

lets say we want to apply finite additivity to only $N$ events (such that $N$ is finite). In this case too we can construct an infinite union using  $A_n=∅$  for $n> N$ (and $n< \infty$) and apply countable union axiom on it. It will prove finite union.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. This question is quite old, and it already has a good answer that basically states what you wrote in a more precise way. Please, answer old posts *only if* you are adding something substantial to them, or put your energies to better use by answering more recent questions.